# MySQL Multiple INNER JOIN + GROUP BY not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am generating a Member Leaderboard based on some field values.. Using Below SQL i am getting those values...

```
SELECT ue1.user_id, 
   ue1.meta_value coins ,
   ue3.meta_value user_rank ,
   ue2.meta_value gems,
   COUNT(ue4.user_id) quiz_count,
   COUNT(ue5.user_id) video_watch_count,
   ue1.meta_value + ue3.meta_value + ue2.meta_value total_points

   FROM `wp_usermeta` as ue1

   INNER JOIN `wp_usermeta` as ue2 ON ue2.user_id = ue1.user_id
     AND ue1.meta_key = '_coin_points' 
     AND ue2.meta_key = '_gem_points'

  INNER JOIN `wp_usermeta` as ue3 ON ue3.user_id = ue1.user_id
     AND ue3.meta_key = '_user_rank'

  INNER JOIN `wp_gamipress_user_earnings` as ue4 ON ue4.user_id = ue1.user_id
    AND ue4.post_type = 'quiz-game-master'

  INNER JOIN `wp_gamipress_user_earnings` as ue5 ON ue5.user_id = ue1.user_id
     AND ue5.post_type = 'video-game-master'

  WHERE ue1.meta_value > 0 

  AND   ue2.meta_value > 0 

  GROUP BY ue1.user_id, ue1.meta_value, ue2.meta_value, ue3.meta_value, ue4.user_id, ue5.user_id

  ORDER BY total_points DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

What i am getting is... Not Expected Query Result

[image: Not Expected Query Result]

See? video_watch_count is copying quiz_count value.. I don't know why? Would appreciate if you could help me out here.

Comment: if you remove the GROUP BY / COUNT() from query you will understand what happens as the COUNT will count the joins aswell.. You need to COUNT in a subquery. ... `SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT()... )` AS alias when counting on many-to-many or one-to-many relations which is the best option but `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` should also work..

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e- try `GROUP BY ue1.user_id, ue1.meta_value, ue2.meta_value, ue3.meta_value`.

Answer (score 0):

Check you join statement. For both `quiz_count, video_watch_count,` you select data from table `wp_gamipress_user_earnings`. For each entry if join condition satisfied it will return `user_id` from corresponding table.

Finally you group it using `user_id` which is common to both join results.That's why you get same count.

Comment: I tried using different field like post_id but gives same copy value...

Comment: Remove second join condition on filed `post_type`. You should use `case` statement to take actual count on `quiz_count` and `vidow_watch_count` just like this. `COUNT(CASE WHEN ue4.post_type = 'quiz-game-master' THEN 1 END) AS quiz_count, COUNT(CASE WHEN ue5.post_type = 'video-game-master' THEN 1 END) AS video_watch_count`

Comment: Give sample data and you expected result and update your question. It will be useful to give a complete solution.

Comment: when i remove second join condition on filed post_type and add `COUNT(CASE WHEN ue4.post_type = 'quiz-game-master' THEN 1 END) AS quiz_count, COUNT(CASE WHEN ue5.post_type = 'video-game-master' THEN 1 END) AS video_watch_count` as you suggested it gives wrong values...